# No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"events"} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events, controller, routes, action

i'm working on a Rails app and after trying to add a "Edit Event" link, I've been getting the following error.

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"events"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Down below is my index.html.haml

```
.event_con
  %h1 Things you've done
  - @events_own.each do |event|
    .event_title
      = event.activity
    .event_rating
      %strong Rating : 
      = event.rating
      &#47 10
    .event_when
      %strong Started : 
      = event.time.to_s(:short)
    .event_end
      %strong Ended : 
      = event.timetwo.to_s(:short)
    .event_notes
      %strong Notes :
      = event.notes

    = link_to "Edit", edit_event_path
```

And here is my Events controller :

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /events
  # GET /events.json
  def index
    @events = Event.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @events_own = Event.where(:userid => current_user.id).order("created_at DESC")
    @event = Event.new
  end

  # GET /events/1
  # GET /events/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /events/new
  def new
    @event = Event.new
    config.time_zone = 'London'

  end

  # GET /events/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /events
  # POST /events.json
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    @event.userid = current_user.id
    config.time_zone = 'London'


    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /events/1
  # PATCH/PUT /events/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.update(event_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /events/1
  # DELETE /events/1.json
  def destroy
    @event.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to events_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_event
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:activity, :time, :rating, :notes, :userid, :id, :timetwo)
    end
end
```

If anyone would be able to figure out this bug I would really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to pass the `id`  of `event` which you would like to be edited. Currently you are not passing it which is causing the error

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"events"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

To resolve this issue, use the below updated link and it should be present within the iteration on `@events_own`

```
= link_to "Edit", edit_event_path(event)
```

This will create `edit` links for each `event` correctly.

Comment: Thank you! Quite annoying it was something so simple haha.