# No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"quiz_bs", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events, controller, routes

I'm trying to link to add an Edit Quiz link in my rails app, but am getting this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"quiz_bs", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I have looked at similar posts ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397190/no-route-matches-action-edit-controller-events-missing-required-keys)) but their answers don't seem to solve the problem, even though they present similar situations.

The error is appearing for this line of my `application.html.erb` code:

```
  <li>
    <% if @user.quiz_bs == nil %>
       <%= link_to "Body Structure Quiz", quiz_bs_path %>
    <% else %>
       <%= link_to "Body Structure Quiz ✓", edit_quiz_b_path(id: @user.quiz_bs) %>
    <% end %>
  </li>
```

but the link will also be on my show users page:

```
  <h4>Body Structure</h4>
  <% if @user.quiz_bs == nil %>
    <p><%= link_to "Test Your Body Structure", new_quiz_b_path %></p>
  <% else %>
    <h3><%= @user.quiz_bs.bscode %></h3>
    <p><%= link_to "Retest Results", edit_quiz_b_path(id: @quiz_bs.id) %></p>
  <% end %>
```

Here is my `quiz_bs_controller`:

```
class QuizBsController < ApplicationController
before_action :require_sign_in

def show
  @quiz_bs = QuizBs.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @quiz_bs = current_user.quiz_bs || current_user.build_quiz_bs
end

def create
  @quiz_bs = QuizBs.new

  @quiz_bs.bs01 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs01]
  @quiz_bs.bs02 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs02]
  @quiz_bs.bs03 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs03]
  @quiz_bs.bs04 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs04]
  @quiz_bs.bs05 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs05]
  @quiz_bs.bs06 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs06]

  @quiz_bs.user = current_user

if @quiz_bs.save
  flash[:notice] = "Quiz results saved successfully."
  redirect_to user_path(current_user)
else
  flash[:alert] = "Sorry, your quiz results failed to save."
  redirect_to welcome_index_path
end
end

def edit
@quiz_bs = QuizBs.find(params[:id])

@quiz_bs.assign_attributes(quiz_bs_params)

if @quiz_bs.save
  flash[:notice] = "Post was updated successfully."
  redirect_to user_path(current_user)
else
  flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
  redirect_to welcome_index_path
end
end

def update
@quiz_bs = QuizBs.find(params[:id])

@quiz_bs.assign_attributes(quiz_bs_params)

if @quiz_bs.save
  flash[:notice] = "Post was updated successfully."
  redirect_to user_path(current_user)
else
  flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
  redirect_to welcome_index_path
end
end

private
def quiz_bs_params
params.permit(:bs01, :bs02, :bs03, :bs04, :bs05, :bs06)
end

end
```

And the corresponding routes are:

```
        quiz_bs GET    /quiz_bs(.:format)             quiz_bs#index
                POST   /quiz_bs(.:format)             quiz_bs#create
     new_quiz_b GET    /quiz_bs/new(.:format)         quiz_bs#new
    edit_quiz_b GET    /quiz_bs/:id/edit(.:format)    quiz_bs#edit
         quiz_b GET    /quiz_bs/:id(.:format)         quiz_bs#show
                PATCH  /quiz_bs/:id(.:format)         quiz_bs#update
                PUT    /quiz_bs/:id(.:format)         quiz_bs#update
```

I would be so grateful for any help figuring out the problem here!

Comment: `<%= link_to "Body Structure Quiz ✓", edit_quiz_b_path(id: @quiz_bs.id) %>`

Comment: In application.html.erb page the value of @quiz_bs is nil due to that it's give the error

Comment: Just a note: the `edit` method should not be doing any processing, it's just responsible for rendering the page. So, you just want `@quiz_bs = QuizBs.find(params[:id])` and that's all.

Comment: @7urkm3n I made this change, but now I get `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: What page are you linking from?  That page probably does not have `@quiz_bs` defined

Comment: @Liz that means your `@quiz_bs` is nil

Comment: @GoGoCarl Thanks for the tip on the edit method.  I'm linking from the `application.html.erb` page and again from the users `show.html.erb` page.

Comment: @Liz post the view for users/show.

Comment: Most likely there is code iterating over `@user.quiz_bs.each do |quiz_b|` and you just want to link to `quiz_b` instead of `@quiz_b`, but just want to be sure...

Comment: @GoGoCarl the linking part of the view is `<p><%= link_to "Retest Results", edit_quiz_b_path(@quiz_bs) %></p>`.  Let me know if you want to see the whole thing, but this is the relevant part.

Comment: @GoGoCarl I don't think there is code iterating over `@user.quiz_bs.each do |quiz_b|` but I edited the original post to show more of the users show page.

Comment: @Liz see my answer below. The issue is indeed your reference.  If you want to post `application.html.erb` I can look at that one as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `application.html.erb`, change to:

```
  <li>
    <% if current_user.quiz_bs.nil? %>
       <%= link_to "Body Structure Quiz", quiz_bs_path %>
    <% else %>
       <%= link_to "Body Structure Quiz ✓", edit_quiz_b_path(current_user.quiz_bs) %>
    <% end %>
  </li>
```

- We want to change `@user` to `current_user`, as this view is a template for the entire website.  There is no guarantee that `@user` will be a global variable in each and every controller (and that's probably not what you want here anyway).  Using the `current_user` method will always be available, and get you the logged in user.
- Note: the `id:` here is not necessary, the model passed will be used as the id.

In `users/show.html.erb`, change to:

```
  <h4>Body Structure</h4>
  <% if @user.quiz_bs == nil %>
    <p><%= link_to "Test Your Body Structure", new_quiz_b_path %></p>
  <% else %>
    <h3><%= @user.quiz_bs.bscode %></h3>
    <p><%= link_to "Retest Results", edit_quiz_b_path(@user.quiz_bs) %></p>
  <% end %>
```

- `@quiz_b` is a variable that you would not have defined in your `users_controller` like you do in the `quiz_bs_controller`. You are accessing `@user.quiz_bs`, so you want to link to that particular instance in your code.

The global `@quiz_b` only works on pages where you have defined this variable, which would be any page under the `quiz_b` routes.

Finally, in `quiz_bs_controller`:

```
def quiz_bs_params
  params.require(:quiz_bs).permit(:bs01, :bs02, :bs03, :bs04, :bs05, :bs06)
end
```

When using this method in conjunction with a form declared as:

```
<%= form_for @quiz_bs do |f| %>
```

You need to require `:quiz_bs` from your `params` in order to scope your parameters to the model being edited in the form; in this case, `@quiz_bs`. Otherwise, no variables will be found when you do update/create the quiz.

Comment: I'm still getting an error referencing the link on the `application.html.erb` page (unfortunately I don't think it even got to the users show page yet), but with this changed link the error moves up from the line of the link to the `<% if @user.quiz_bs == nil %>` line to say that `undefined method 'quiz_bs' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: And I added more context for the application view as well.

Comment: @Liz I updated my answer.  But, one thing -- can a user have more than one quiz_b?

Comment: It sounds like you should be calling `@user.quiz_b` (singular)

Comment: A user `has_one :quiz_bs`, if that's what you're asking.  Ideally they would take it once via the new view, then everything after that would edit that record...

Comment: And even after your updates I'm getting `undefined method 'quiz_bs' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Yes, `@user` is nil.  Have you defined `@user` somewhere?  In your controller?  Because you are using the main `application` view, `user` needs to be defined *EVERYWHERE* in your app.  If you're using devise or the like, a quick fix would be to replace this with `current_user` instead to get the logged in user.  Happy to hop in a chat and discuss...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110560/discussion-between-liz-and-gogocarl).

Comment: @Liz Updated for posterity. I think that covers it all!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"quiz_bs", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

You have to pass the Edit action an ID, it's part of the routing structure.  In your routes output it even shows you this:

```
/quiz_bs/:id/edit
```

Without that id, the /:id/edit route is simply not going to work -- that is a Rails mechanism.

In your Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'pry-rails'
end
```

And:

```
bundle install
```

Then in your `application.html.erb` above that logic do:

```
<% binding.pry %>
<% if @user.quiz_bs == nil %>
    <p><%= link_to "Test Your Body Structure", new_quiz_b_path %></p>
<% else %>
    <h3><%= @user.quiz_bs.bscode %></h3>
    <p><%= link_to "Retest Results", edit_quiz_b_path(id: @quiz_bs.id) %></p>
<% end %>
```

Now hit the page again.  Pry will cause a debug breakpoint that will allow you to evaluate the @user object in the terminal where your server is currently running.  My best advice to you is to learn to debug your own code -- this is a situation with a lot of context you can't quite provide without providing access to your app.